# My subdomain .NET project is not directing to my startup file

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

My wedding is coming up and I've printed 100 invites directing my guests to http://wedding.mydomain.com.  Similar to a stand-alone project, I've set my startup page to my Default.aspx page as demonstrated here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/12/16/set-as-start-page-vstipproj0027.aspx.

However, when directed toward http://wedding.mydomain.com, I get a 'Maintenance' page.  I have to manually go to http://wedding.mydomain.com/Default.aspx, to get the desired project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might need to set the default document.

If you have an using IIS7(+) windows hosting you can set the default document in your web.config like

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <add value="default.aspx" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you are using the Plesk interface refer to this article: https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6853/changing-your-windows-hosting-accounts-default-file

Comment: Boom amazing.  Thanks for the Plesk article.  I don't have enough rep to upvote yet, but thank you so, so much.